# Pnp powershell boolean field

Tags: pnp-powershell

I want to create a boolean site column (yes/no field) througn pnp power shell.
I used Add-PnPField command, but how to set default value to "no"

Answer (score 6):

After you create your field using `Add-PnPField`, you need to get that field using `Get-PnPField` and set the default value as below:

```
$field = Get-PnPField -List CustomList -Identity "BoolField"
$field.DefaultValue = "0"
$field.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Also, you can use `PnPFieldFromXml` itself to create a boolean field with No as default value as :

```
$fieldXml = "<Field Type='Boolean' Name='TestBool' StaticName='TestBool' DisplayName='Test Bool'><Default>0</Default></Field>"
Add-PnPFieldFromXml -FieldXml $fieldXml
```

References - [Add-PnPFieldFromXml](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfieldfromxml?view=sharepoint-ps)

[Create fields using CSOM](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/my-articles/creating-fields-using-csom/)

Comment: hey @gokulnath, hope that helped you. You can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will earn you the learner badge as well as remove it from the unanswered questions list ! Cheers, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile you can add boolean values with PNP

```
$DisplayName = "Win"
$PNPField = Add-PnPField -List $List -DisplayName $DisplayName -InternalNameDisplayName -Type Boolean -AddToDefaultView
```

Source: https://sposcripts.com/add-sharepoint-columns-with-powershell/#Add_Boolean_Column